# Update ad creatives without loosing likes and shares

Tags: facebook-ads-api, adgroup

Using Facebook Ads API, we can create new creative set, and replace it in the ad group, but this result in loosing the performance records (and engagement).

Is there anyway to update the picture/text without loosing the performance records ?

Comment: if you're using a page post, can't you just re-use the page post in subsequent adcreatives?

Comment: @PaulBain Thanks Paul. What if it's not a page post. In our case, we want to change the creatives (Picture) to be exact every few hours for the same promoted ad. To do so, every few hours: 1. We create new adimage; 2. We create new ad creative; 3. We update the adgroup to use the new adcreative. What's happening is that we are loosing the likes and comments already collected on post.

Comment: if you're creating a new post each time, it's not expected that the likes and comments on the old post would transfer to the new because they're different things

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you will lose the likes and comments every time you change your creative.
It makes sense though.
Let's say I like your ad because it had a nice image of a dog.
Then you'll change the image to be image of a cat.
If I see your ad again, containing image of a cat and it shows me that I liked it, I would be upset (as I don't like cats...).
Therefore, you should not be able to carry the likes and comments when changing the image.

Regarding "performance records", AFAK, these ones do carry on when you change your creative, as they are in the ad/adset/campaign level.